# Load data from two OneToMany relationships

Tags: jpa

I want to display data from a database with JPA on the frontend, i.e. display the `Person`'s details. Details can be *0..n* `Adresse`s and *0..m* `Phone`s. The entities are shown below:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable { 
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private int id;
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
   private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
   private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();   
   // plus     getter and setter
}

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable { 
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @ManyToOne
   private Person person;
   private String onestring;         // plus getter and setter
}

@Entity
public class Phone implements Serializable { 
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @ManyToOne
   private Person person;
   private String anotherstring;         // plus getter and setter
}
```

As lazy loading is activated, ...

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public Person getPerson(int id) {
   return em.find(Person .class, id);
}
```

... would only provide proxies on `adresses` and `phones`.

Questions:

1. What is good way displaying the all data on the frontend, i.e. the person and all its addesses and phones? (Except for setting FetchType to EAGER).
2. Is there a way to fetch both `addresses` and `phones` into the same instance of `Person` or do I have to fetch the `Person` twice (one time with `addresses`, one time with `phones`) to omit a cartesian product?

Comment: Why can't you use the eager fetchtype?  This is provider specific - some providers have optimizations such as batch fetching.  What provider are you using?

Comment: @Chris: I use hibernate. I want to omit using FetchType EAGER because the Entity Person has more OneToMany-Relationships. Therefore, I want to control which data is loaded and which not.

Comment: I am really confused. Is the answer to this question so obvious? I could not find any solution anywhere - or best practice. Maybe I am searching for the wrong key words. Any idea on how to ideally deal with this data structure? Thanks

Comment: What would be the best strategy to fetch the data? Any ideas?

Comment: Fetch the person and then access the lazy relationships to trigger them being fetched.  see http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/ for others and FetchGrapfh/LoadGraph to load what is neeeded with a single query dynamically https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm